# Convert Webpage to Image with Scaling for DPI

Tags: printing, images, conversion, webpage

I need to convert a webpage to an image for publication in a magazine. I've found several applications and websites that will do this for me, but the resulting image, no matter how large I make it, is scaled for 96 dpi.

By this I mean, I use an application/web page to load the target page, tell it to make it 2250p (7.5 inches) for printing, but when they finish, it's still scaled at ~100 dpi.

So how can I automate loading a webpage, setting its size, and scaling the page to ~300% so that the page screenshot comes out at ~300 dpi for printing?

Comment: Maybe you could try 'printing' the page in Chrome and choose PDF as the destination? If you need an actual image file, you can probably convert the PDF to image, but there will be some weird page breaks. Alternatively, you could try to find another print driver if none of the other browser extensions work.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ Mark: That may not be a bad option. Hadn't thought about that. Tested your suggestion out and it does appear to print the text at 300dpi. And there are print to image drivers so... will look into it further and report back.

Comment: I removed the software rec part of your question since it's off-topic here, as indicated by Davidenko above.